# In premake 3.7, how do I generate -O0 instead of -O2 for gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, premake

It seems that -O2 is always generated unless I specify "optimize-speed" (which results in -O3) or "optimize-size" (which results in -Os) in **buildflags**. If I specify nothing in **buildflags** but pass "-O0" into **buildoptions** the result is "-O2 -O0". The expected result, however, would be just "-O0".

How can I prevent the generation of "-O2" when I pass "-O0" as a custom build option? The documentation mentions nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a method to turn -02 off, but it is not necessarry.

From GCC manpage:

> If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such
>              option is the one that is effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try building it in Debug configuration instead of Release?

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that -O2 appears to cause a crash in the release build while -O0 doesn't, and for the time being it's important to have a crash-free release build, even if it is not optimized. Anyway, you're saying that premake doesn't allow anything lower than -O2 for release builds?

Comment: @pholz, I know this is old, but just to make a point: If your program crashes with the compiler option `-O2`, but not with `-O0`, then it probably means that there is a problem with your code, which just happens to work in this one case. On another platform or computer or with different data it might be different. (I had to learn this the hard way.)